# Jquery .load() removes highlight.js classes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, highlight.js

In my php chat, everytime a message is submitted i use `.load()` to refresh the div content on my ajax request. after the .load method is called, highlight.js classes dissapear.

Highlight.js init

```
$(document).ready(function() {

hljs.configure({useBR: true});
$('div.sendermsg , div.receivermsg').each(function(i, block) 
  {
  hljs.highlightBlock(block);
  });

});
```

Chat divs

```
foreach($n as $x) { if ($x['username'] == $username) {?>

<tr>
<td class="sendertd">
<div class="sendermsg"><?php echo $x['message']; ?></div>
</td>
</tr>

<?php }

else { ?>

<tr>
<td class="receivertd">
<div class="receivermsg"><?php echo $x['message']; ?></div>
</td>
</tr>

<?php }
} ?>
```

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
url : "backend/user_to_user.php", 
type : "POST", 
data : {'message':message,'user2':user2},
 success: function(data) 
  {
//syntax is highlighted and works well before this line is called
$(".tbody").load(location.href + " .tbody > *"); 
$(".tbody").scrollTop($(".tbody")[0].scrollHeight);

  }
   });
```

before ajax call (just an example if the posted message is javascript)

[image: before call]

after ajax call

[image: after call]

Any ideas?

EDIT 
quote from jquery.com

`When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed.`

so i've tried

```
$(".tbody").load(location.href+" .tbody > *",function(){
$.getScript("js/highlight.min.js"); 
});
```

still not working

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by adding this after the `.load()`

```
$(".tbody").load(location.href+" .tbody > *");
$.getScript("http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.11.0/highlight.min.js", function () {
$('div.sendermsg , div.receivermsg').each(function(i, block) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
});
});
```